# Display terminal command result in Desktop notification

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, notification, notify-send

I need to display the result of a terminal command in notification.

Notifications can be triggered by running:

```
notify-send "Notification message"
```

The command I have is:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start
```

which shows the following result in terminal:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

I want this result to be displayed in notification just like "Notification message" is displayed with `notify-send`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases you can use `notify-send` with [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `$()`. For example:

```bsh
notify-send "XAMP Start" "$(sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start)"
```

Inside a scrip you can use a function to wrap the entire output:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
main() { echo "Line 1"; echo "Line 2";  echo "Line 3"; }
notify-send "Script output" "$(main)"
```

If you need to run that function with `sudo`:

```bsh
notify-send "Script output" "$(sudo bash -c "$(declare -f main); main")"
```